# how to disable choose button for video in UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, ios, video, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using UIImagePickerController to show the user which all videos he has in his Photos App.
However, I have no functionality to provide if the user clicks on `Choose` button, that comes up with the Cancel and play button on clicking on video thumbnail.

This is how I implement my picker:

```
UIImagePickerController *videoPickerCtrl = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
videoPickerCtrl.delegate = self;
videoPickerCtrl.editing = NO;
videoPickerCtrl.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
NSArray *mediaTypesAllowed = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"public.movie"];
[videoPickerCtrl setMediaTypes:mediaTypesAllowed];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:videoPickerCtrl animated:YES];
```

How can I totally remove/hide the `Choose` button? or can I just disable it, so that the user does not click on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, it is not possible to disable that choose button. Because that is an inbuilt

functionality of UIImagePickerController and you can not make changes in the same.

Comment: so any suggestions on how i should proceed? the user will be able to see the button, with no functionality. I seriously do not want to make a custom image picker just because of this button